# Big O Question - Algorithmic Analysis II

Tags: algorithm, big-o, code-analysis, analysis

I am doing a question which asks to find the complexity of a nested for loop simplified using big O notation.

The question is:

```
for i <- 1 to n do
    for j <- 1 to n do
        for k <- 1 to (i+j) do
            a unit cost operation
```

I HAVE to prove the above using sum of series notation. I am kind of grasping the concept and have given this a crack. I just want to know whether I am doing it correctly or not.

Here is my answer:

**Assume sum(x=i, y) is the capital sigma notation with x as the lower bound and y as the upper bound.

=> sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) sum(k=1, i+j) 1 
=> sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) (i+j)
=> sum(i = 1, n) n*i
=> n * sum (i = 1, n) i

subbing in rule for sum of arithmetic series gives:
=> n*n/2(n+1)
=> (n^3 + n^2) / 2

using big Oh rule -> max(f(x), g(x)):
=> max(n^3/2, n^2/2)
=> O(n^3)

I know the answer is correct but am not sure if my calculations prior to it are....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small correction:

```
  sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) sum(k=1, i+j) 1
= sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) (i+j)
= [ sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) i ] + [ sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) j ]
=   sum(i = 1, n) n*i           +   sum(i=1, n) n*(n+1)/2 
=   n * sum (i = 1, n) i        +   n * n * (n+1) / 2
=   n * n * (n+1) / 2           +   n * n * (n+1) / 2
=   n * n * (n+1)
=   n^3 + n^2
=   O( max(n^3, n^2) )           <--- as you correctly say
=   O(n^3)
```

Actually, it's `Θ(n^3)`

---

You could also use that `i+j <= 2*n`:

```
   sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) sum(k=1, i+j) 1
=  sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) (i+j)
<= sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) 2*n
=  2*n * sum(i=1, n) sum(j=1, n) 1
=  2 * n^3
=  O(n^3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Straightforwardly and formally (and empirically verified), with `c` --> *a unit cost operation*:

[image]